# Batch to compare strings from 1st file to remove complete line on 2nd file

Tags: batch-file, compare, cut, findstr

I need a batch file to pick each string (1 string = 1 line) in a FileA and search for it in FileB and remove the complete line from this FileB that has this string.

I tried several combinations using:

```
findstr /vixg:"FileA" "FileB" >"File.new"
type FileA.txt |findstr /v I%%
```

Do you guys have a solution for that?

Thanks

Comment: What fails when using `findstr /vig:"FileA" "FileB" > "File.new"`  ?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (fileA.txt) do ( type fileB.txt | find "%%~i" /v > fileB.txt )
```

Comment: This actually might work with some tweeks... The above code erases the file after each verification. Some variable need to be set to check only the new file generated after each line is removed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that these statemets can help you:

```
@echo off

set /p A="Insert first file path: "
:: FileA
set /p B="Insert second file path: "
:: FileB

for /f "delims=¶" %%g in (%B%) do (

findstr /c:"%%g" %A% > nul || echo %%g >> TEMP.txt

)

del /P %B%
ren TEMP.txt %B%
pause
```

However, with these statements it is possible to compare entire lines rather than only parts of a line, but I hope this is anyway what are you looking for.

Comment: The fileA has only a piece of what is present on the lines of FileB... I changed the code above a little but it didn't work.

Comment: In order to be more helpful to solve your issue, can you please post example lines from the original FileA, FileB and, in the end, the resulting FileB you are aiming at?

Answer (score 0):

Likely the shortest solution is to use `grep`, the right tool for this particular job. Use the `-f` option to read the patterns from `FileA` instead of from the command line, and the `-v` option to negate matches (i.e. print any line that's *not* matching):

```
grep -v -f FileA FileB
```

Comment: Works perfectly for me.  Do you happen to have DOS/Windows style CR/NL at end of lines by any chance?  If you do, you need to run `dos2unix` on these files first. Also note it is `grep` (lowercase) not `GREP` (uppercase). Are you running in DOS?

Comment: I'm running it in DOS... I just downlaoded a version for DOS and tested what you sent me.

Comment: Ah, well. It's the shortest/simplest solution, but it will only work in environments with a sane (like GNU) `grep` command, and sane line terminators (Newline only). Mac OS-X, FreeBSD, Linux, etc. Sorry.  Hopefully it would be useful for others who use one of these environments.